# Need to check value of hidden input field related to clicked element (multiple with same name)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Title isn't that clear, so let me see if I can explain what I'm doing. 
I'm listing off users' posts, and have a like/comment button with those posts.

What I need to do, is capture when the like button is clicked (`<span>` tags), and then grab the post id from the hidden input field, and use that to post to the PHP script.

The PHP is doing all of the checking for if they're friends, privacy level is correct, etc. before actually submitting the like to the database, but I am currently just having the javascript/jquery be generated when the post is shown (naming each js variable/DOM element according to post id), but that's not very efficient and looks messy when viewing the source (But, it's the only way I can get it to work).

I want to be able to use an external javascript file to check when just the like button is clicked, and know what post that is being liked, and work that way.

I've been looking into this for quite some time, and it's to my understanding that `this` might work, but I have had no luck. I'm generating multiple posts on one page using `foreach()` loop, so the names/ids/classes of the elements are the same.

---

For a little better understanding, here's an example of what a post might look like:

```
<div class="feedPost">
    <img src="#" class="feedProfile"/>
    <a href="#" class="feedName">FirstName LastName</a>
    <div class="feedPostBody">Hello, world!</div>
    <input type="hidden" value="24772" name="feedPostID">
    <span class="feedLikeButton">Like</span> | <a href="#">Comment</a> | 2 mins ago
</div>
```

and, using javascript/jquery, I want to be able to do something like this in an external js file:

```
$('.feedLikeButton').on('click',function(){
  var post_id = 0; //I need to get the ID from the post that the like button is related to.
  //If I just did $('.feedPostID').val() it wouldn't work
  $.post("https://mysite/path/to/like.php", {post: post_id}).done(function(data){
    if(data == "success"){
      //This will set text from "Like" to "Unlike"
      //Again, I can't just do $('.feedLikeButton') to access
      //I guess I could do this.innerHTML? Would still need to access feed post id
    } else {
      //Probably will just flash error to user if error, or something similar
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the like button

```
var likeButton = $(this);
```

Then get it's container

```
var container = likeButton.parent();
```

Then find the hidden field

```
var idInput = container.find('[name="feedPostID"]');
```

Then get it's value:

```
var id = idInput.val();
```

With all these references you can do whatever you want.